# Объект в ArraysList

Tags: java, классы, arraylist, объекты

```
JSONArray messages = result.getJSONObject("messages").getJSONArray("list");
List<Messages> messagesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < messages.length(); i++){
 Messages message = new Messages();
 message.setTitle(messages.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
 message.setDescription(messages.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
 message.setDate(messages.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"));
 message.setType(messages.getJSONObject(i).getString("type"));
 messagesArrayList.add(message);
}
callback.onSuccess(messagesArrayList);
```

Добавляю в массива объекты. но после передачи массива через callback, вызов функций типа getTitle() getDescription() не работают. Якобы их нету вообще.

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(List messages) {
   Log.e("title", messages.get(0).getTitle());
}
```

Comment: Все прошу прощения, разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

```
Messages m = (Messages)messages.get(0);
Log.e("title", m.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле проблема у вас в том, что у `List` в аргументе метода не параметризован, т.е. не указан тип данных в списке. Зисим, они по умолчанию воспринимаются как экземпляры класса `Object`. Вам надо просто указать тип данных в агрументе метода так `List<Messages>`:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(List<Messages> messages) {
   Log.e("title", messages.get(0).getTitle());
}
```